# OpenGL - Create a border over a textured polygon

Tags: opengl, textures, shader, cocos2d-x

I'm working with cocos2d-x 2.0.4. I illustrate what I am trying to do through these two images.

[image: convex_poly]

[image: convex_poly_with_border]

What i want to do is to create a blurred border or a border with a gradient on it programmatically. I have two ideas to do that but I'm not sure if it is the correct way to do. First solution would be to triangulate the polygon containing only the blurred color (concave polygon with a hole in this case) and rendering color on it with a gradient, vertices on the outside of the polygon would be full-alpha and vertices on the inside zero-alpha. The interpolation would do the job of gradient then.
Second solution would be to do it inside the shader itself. All I need is to calculate the distance from a pixel and the closest edge of the polygon to it. Then under a certain threshold I affect pixel white color with a certain alpha value depending on that distance (the shortest the distance is, the biggest alpha is).

Anyway I am very new to openGL stuff and I am afraid that the second solution will end up with big processing time as I have to calculate the distance for every pixel of the polygon. What do you think about this guys? Any ideas the tend to confirm my guesses or am I completely wrong on this?

EDIT:
The solution I finally chose was to use the bisector of every angle (easy to calculate with 3 consecutive vertices) in the polygon and take a point on that bisector that would become a vertex for the inner polygon. Then i take either a outer polygon vertex or a inner polygon vertex to build an array of vertices that can fit the GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP parameter. I put the image below to understand better.

[image: expl]

Comment: Just a general comment, but you need to think in terms of triangles, and not arbitrary polygons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Will a rim lighting shader do what you want? [Link to an example](http://www.catalinzima.com/samples/rim-lighting/)

Example code for a GLSL rim lighting shader:

```
const float rimStart = 0.5f;
const float rimEnd = 1.0f;
const float rimMultiplier = 0.0f;
vec3  rimColor = vec3(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

float NormalToCam = 1.0 - dot(normalize(outNormal), normalize(camPos - vertexWorldPos.xyz));
float rim = smoothstep(rimStart, rimEnd, NormalToCam) * rimMultiplier;

outColor.rgb += (rimColor * rim);
```

Comment: Really interesting, I will take a look at that ;)

Comment: I am working on a 2D project so there is not this notion of depth and I guess the NormalToCam float value has no sense in my case. I keep it for my future 3D projects ;)

Comment: Well, you still have a notion of depth! Everything just happens to share the same depth. I wonder if you could make normals along the outside of your poly point orthogonal to the camera, and normals on the inside point parallel to the camera. That might make it work for you. Either way I SUSPECT the technique can be adapted somehow.

Comment: Alternatively you could do it in multiple render passes, one where you scale the poly a bit, and then do a few passes for a Gaussian blur, then mask it against the unmodified polygon.

Answer (score 1):

In order to make this look right from any viewpoint in a 3D scene you will need to perform some silhouetting. This essentially involves using a geometry shader to determine what edges of an object have an adjacent face that is facing the screen and an adjacent face that is not facing the screen. I believe this can be achieved by testing if the dot product between one adjacent face normal and your camera direction is <= 0 while the dot product of the other adjacent face normal and your camera direction is > 0.

Once you know all the edges that outline your polygon at a certain angle, you can tessellate the polygon defined by that border into triangle-strips (still in geometry shader). Then, you will pass a color per vertex to your fragment shader; where all vertices lying on the border pass the border color at full alpha and non-border points pass a color at zero alpha . The fragment shader will interpolate from border color to center alpha color at intermediate fragments giving you the gradient you want. Your total approach should be something like this:

1. Draw object with non-border shader program as the background color.
2. Enable alpha blending.

   ```
   glEnable(GL_BLEND);
   glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA,GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
   ```
3. Draw object with silhouetting program determining the edges that make up  the borders with the border color, and drawing non-border points as zero alpha.
4. ```
   glDisable(GL_BLEND);
   ```

Comment: Actually it is a 2D project but your method confirms mine, and I think this should work. Thx;)

Comment: No problem! I'm so used to thinking in a 3d headspace I just totally forgot people used OpenGL for 2D drawing. Good luck!